# find the last record in SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

This is actually part of a Massive SQL query, but I had this code working, and now I cant seem to figure out why its not finding the last appointment record.

What I am trying to do is join all the other appointments onto themselves to find out which one is the last one. And all my results appear to be null. But this is not correct because my data definitely have appointments. So I think there is something wrong with my select query. Any help would be great.

```
SELECT `animal_id`, 
       FROM_UNIXTIME(`lastappointment`.`appointmentdata_starttime`,'%D %M %Y') AS 'Last Appointment'
FROM `animal`
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT `lAppointment`.*
    FROM `appointment` AS `lAppointment`
    LEFT JOIN `appointment` AS `nlAppointment` 
       ON `nlAppointment`.`appointmentdata_starttime` <= NOW()
           AND `nlAppointment`.`appointmentdata_starttime` > `lAppointment`.`appointmentdata_starttime`
           AND `nlAppointment`.`appointmentdata_animal` = `lAppointment`.`appointmentdata_animal`
    WHERE `lAppointment`.`appointmentdata_starttime` <= NOW() 
       AND `nlAppointment`.`appointment_id` IS NULL
    ) AS `lastappointment` 
    ON `animal_id` = `lastappointment`.`appointmentdata_animal`
WHERE `animaldata_active` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY animal_id;
```

Comment: Are you sure that `appointment`.`appointmentdata_animal` is the same as `animal`.`animal_id`?

Comment: yep. appointment.appointmentdata_animal is a FK with a constraint to animal.animal_id

Comment: In the absence of any sorting there is no "last one"

Comment: When I mean last appointment, I mean the last appointment record that happened before NOW() for that animal, and I also want to exclude everything that has a starttime greater than NOW() because they may be appointments booked for the future.

Comment: Can you not achieve this with "SELECT ... FROM appointment WHERE appointmentdata_starttime` <= NOW() ORDER BY appointmentdata_starttime` DESC LIMIT 1"

Answer (score 0):

Using LEFT JOINs to get the MAX() is the slowest method you can think of. I recommend you to change the inner query like this (using GROUP BY):

```
SELECT `animal_id`,
  FROM_UNIXTIME(`lastappointment`.`last_appointment`, '%D %M %Y') AS 'Last Appointment'
FROM `animal`
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT MAX(appointmentdata_starttime) AS last_appointment,
         appointmentdata_animal
  FROM appointment
  WHERE appointmentdata_starttime <= NOW()
  GROUP BY appointmentdata_animal
  ) AS `lastappointment` 
       ON `animal_id` = `lastappointment`.`appointmentdata_animal`
WHERE `animaldata_active` IS NOT NULL
-- GROUP BY animal_id; --BTW, this group_by is not needed
```